Is it possible to store bytes in raw format with no space overhead?
I am using heapq and would like the values to be raw bytes to be compared alphabetically. I want to use as little space as possible. Strings, even byte strings, unfortunately come with a space overhead. For example, take this MWE with fake data:
from heapq import heappush
from pympler.asizeof import asizeof
L=[]
for _ in range(10_000):
    heappush(L, ("abcd"*3).encode('latin1'))
print(f"{asizeof(L)} bytes")

This outputs 565176 bytes. I would really like it to take closer to 120000 bytes.
Is this possible?

The only overhead should be a length and a pointer to the byte data, probably another 12 bytes per byte string. The rest is probably the overhead of the heap.

If all the byte strings are the same length, maybe you could use a numpy array.

If all the byte strings are of the same size as they are in your question, you can pack them into a bytearray such that the offset of a byte string at a given index would simply be the index multiplied by the size of each byte string.
Since heapq.heappush does not know about such an access method to a bytearray, we can make it operate instead on a container that provides a list-like interface to the underlying bytearray of packed byte strings of a fixed given size:
class BytesArray:
    def __init__(self, item_size):
        self.item_size = item_size
        self.value = bytearray()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.value) // self.item_size

    def _slice(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self):
            offset = index * self.item_size
            return slice(offset, offset + self.item_size)
        raise IndexError

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.value[self._slice(index)]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.value[self._slice(index)] = value

    def append(self, value):
        self.value += value

But then the C implementation of heapq, namely the _heapq module, can only deal with actual lists but not non-list like-like objects, so we need to force-import its Python implementation by setting sys.modules['_heapq'] to None before importing heapq:
import sys
sys.modules['_heapq'] = None
from heapq import heappush

With that done, the following test code of yours using our BytesArray container of item size 12:
L = BytesArray(12)
for _ in range(10_000):
    heappush(L, ("abcd"*3).encode('latin1'))
print(f"{asizeof(L)} bytes")

now outputs:
132200 bytes

This is not as close to the desired size of 120000 bytes as it can be because for efficiency reasons bytearray over-allocates its buffer by 12.5% as it grows incrementally. To eliminate the over-allocation, you can re-create the bytearray after you're done with all the heappushs:
L.value = bytearray(L.value)
print(f"{asizeof(L)} bytes")

This would then output:
120544 bytes

where the extra 544 bytes is just the overhead of the instance itself.

Ha, I had done the same thing and it took me about three seconds of glancing to correctly guess that this is you :-)

In another question they reported apparently actually using much more memory. Not sure why and how to interpret it, and I couldn't reproduce it on two systems I tried. I could understand it with this, the bytearray temporarily needing much extra space when extending beyond its capacity and it reallocates. If that happens, my next idea was to not use one bytearray but a list of bytearrays of let's say one megabyte each. That could also reduce the overhead compared to this, if they have many more entries, as the one bytearray overallocates by 12.5%.

Thanks. I learned from the best SO user of bytearray. ;-) Your list of bytearrays strategy sounds plausible, but since each one-megabyte bytearray also gets the same percentage of over-allocation, chances are that there's going to be a similar amount of over-allocation in the end. With your strategy, however, if we are to eliminate over-allocations by re-creating all the bytearrays, the re-creation of small bytearrays at least won't require as much available space as re-creating a huge bytearray so it will still help indeed.

Yeah, originally I was only concerned about a potential doubling of memory during a reallocation. The small bytearrays could indeed be recreated your way, or we could always use fixed 1 MB and write into them instead of appending. But I wouldn't do any of that unless they actually have an issue with your current solution.

Oh, one idea that might work well: Elsewhere I think they replied to "How many entries do you have?" with "As many as I can", suggesting they can control it. In that case, they could decide the limit in advance and preallocate one big bytearray and write into it instead of appending. Like self.value = bytearray(n * 12) for n entries. Could even save Python-level operations then, by storing the i-th entry in self.value[i::n] (but the "cache-unfriendlyness" might make it slower).

Strings have an overhead of about 40 bytes per string.  You can see this by looking at sys.getsizeof(''), etc.
You've got 10_000 strings, each taking up about 52 bytes.  That's where your space is going.
